# Modules not being recognised

Tags: python, anaconda, sentiment-analysis, youtube-dl

I am trying to import a function from another file within the same folder as my code, although the file(module) and function are not being recognised.

**Code**

```
   import streamlit as st
   from save_audio import save_audio
   from configure import auth_key
   import pandas as pd
   from time import sleep
   import urllib.request
   import plotly.express as px
   import plotly.graph_objects as go
   from urllib.request import urlopen
   from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
   import json
   import requests
```

**Error**

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'save_audio'
```

**I have tried:**

- uninstalling and re-installing all libraries in terminal using pip3 as I am using Python3
- Making sure all files are in the same folder

I am using Anaconda if that helps. I am trying to do sentiment analysis using youtube audio.

Comment: Do you happen to have `__init__.py` file in the same working directory? If this file is missing, `save_audio` will not be recognized as a module.

Comment: Are you calling that code as a script? Posting the full traceback may help with that. You could `import sys;print(sys.path[0])` at the start of your code to see if the code's directory is there.

Comment: ...and I assume that `save_audio.py` is the local file causing problems.

Comment: Ok so I tried the __init__.py solution although this did not seem to solve it. Do I add __init__.py as a file in the root directory or the same directory I am trying to import save_audio in? Also, with import sys;print(sys.path[0]) you can see that the root directory has the name sentimentanalysis so instead of using 'from save_audio import save_audio' I used from sentimentanalysis import save_audio although the same error occurred. It said it didn't recognise sentimentanalysis.

Comment: Also I have python 3.9 and I downloaded youtube_dl and streamlit in my terminal using pip.